# Creating an array with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to create JSON objects in Java. I am trying to make an array with three elements:

```
[ "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" ]
```

With this code:

```
    JsonArray   array   = new JsonArray ();
    array.add("ONE");
    array.add("TWO");
    array.add("THREE");
```

But the `add()` only accepts a `JsonElement` object, rather than an actual string.

---

The reason I'm under the impression I should be able to do this, is because I've used a C# script called [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) with Unity3D in the past. With it, I could do this:

```
    JSONArray ary = new JSONArray ();
    ary.Add("ONE");
    ary.Add("TWO");
    ary.Add("THREE");
```

Which works fine. I'm just not sure how to do this with gson.

---

I know I can *convert* a Java array into a `JSON` object:

```
String[] strings = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
gson.toJson(strings);  ==> prints ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

However, I want to dynamically createobjects in a `JsonArray` (the `Add` method), like I can with C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JsonPrimitive](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/r302/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html). You should be able to use `array.add(new JsonPrimitive(yourString);`

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to do that with [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)s, which are really easy to manipulate.
You can add your [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s to a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and then create a JSON from it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("ONE");
list.add("TWO");
list.add("THREE");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String array = gson.toJson(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("ONE"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("TWO"));
array.add(new JsonPrimitive("THREE"));
```

Answer (score 1):

array.add(gson.toJsonTree ("ONE"));